# Error While downloading image from instagram

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

Hi everyone I am having İnvalid scheme and much error with this code

i am just trying to make a simple instagram image downloader from given url
here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_response(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    while not r.ok:
        return r.status_code
    return r.text

url = input('Enter Instagram URL: ')
response = get_response(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

image = soup.find("meta", property="og:image")
image = str(image)
image = image.replace("amp;","")
print(image)                    ### Here is working fine when you click printed link it works 

r = requests.get(image)         ### Problem is at here
with open('cat3.jpg', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(r.content)

# https://www.instagram.com/p/CL1TxMRlhe7/ #sample cat image
```

ERRORS LİSTED HERE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Python öğreniyorum\ana_dosya.py", line 20, in <module>
    r = requests.get(image)         ### Problem is at here

  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)

  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '<meta content="https://instagram.fsaw3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/155344637_426370308591690_7809000723152066300_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fsaw3-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=sP6bYsFdL_0AX8yIuXZ&oh=a7e381762b429e6c7b3b494b510ca166&oe=60790CBF" property="og:image"/>'
```

Comment: As shown in the very last line of your error message, you are trying to send a request to a URL that is invalid. It is invalid because it contains the HTML tag `meta`. You have to grab the URL that is in the `content` attribute of the HTML code.

Comment: thanks i solved :) i made a quick fix like image = image[15:-23]  and get the pure url link and it worked i will make it with re sub later :) thanks

Comment: I have posted a proper answer to your question that is more robust than the one you have come up with. If it works, please click the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the very last line of your error message you are trying to send a request to a URL that is invalid. It is invalid because it contains the HTML tag `meta`. You have to grab the URL that is in the `content` attribute of the HTML code.

Here is the code that you need in order to get the URL to the Instagram image:

```py
image = soup.find("meta", property="og:image")["content"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone ı Solved it
quick fix is trim the meta content and og property text inside image string and it worked